# regex Как вытащить название магазина из данной строки?

Tags: регулярные-выражения

```
Finish: Painted(write color)
Personalization: Could you please paint this in gold? If there's no gold,
the "honey" color is fine
Магазин: Wooden Reds_76
Идентификатор транзакции: 2064208676
Количество: 1
Цена: 39,95 US$
Personalized item
```

Нужно достать строку "Wooden Reds_76"
У меня получилось только буквы: `.*Магазин: (\w+)`, но в названии могут быть ещё и цифры, и пробелы

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вот так вот:

```
(?<=Магазин:\h).*
```

Тест https://regexr.com/5d5t5

```
Finish: Painted(write color)
Personalization: Could you please paint this in gold? If there's no gold,
the "honey" color is fine
Магазин: Wooden Reds_76
Идентификатор транзакции: 2064208676
Количество: 1
Цена: 39,95 US$
Personalized item
```

Comment: Интересный спецификатор `\h`, типа "Horizontal whitespace", это какой-то новодел? Не помню в Perl 5 такого. Хм ... Откуда это?

Comment: @Majestio в PCRE грамматике такой, Perl не знаю. Можно использовать " " или "\s", в зависимости от потребностей и реализации регулярок у ТС

Comment: Вот и я об этом ... `\s` как-то привычнее.

Comment: @Majestio у меня тоже глаз зацепился. Оказалось, он ещё в 5.10 появился https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass#Backslash-sequences

Comment: Хм ... интересно, и даже полезно

Comment: @Majestio давно хотел спросить, почему на тебе аватарка, которую я [тоже] таскаю года с 2007-2008 + ты тоже в perl умеешь? :)

Comment: Аватарка - давно понравилась) А с Perl'ом познакомился в 1998 году. С тех пор им пользуюсь всегда и везде, где уместно.

Answer (score 3):

```
Магазин:\s*([^\r\n]*)
```

```js
console.log(`
Finish: Painted(write color)
Personalization: Could you please paint this in gold? If there's no gold,
the "honey" color is fine
Магазин: Wooden Reds_76
Идентификатор транзакции: 2064208676
Количество: 1
Цена: 39,95 US$
Personalized item
`.match(/Магазин:\s*([^\r\n]*)/)[1])
```

Comment: `Магазин:\s*([^\r\n]*)` скорее всего. Хотя если один пробел между названием и значением гарантирован - не вопрос тогда.

Comment: @Majestio, да, так будет лучше. Обновил.